# Angular Jasmine Unit test Expected spy unknown not to have been called with ... but it was

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, spy

I am trying to test a condition where a spy should be called twice and fail once, so I have setup the following.

In the controller there is a listener which takes a time, and only if the day has changed does it invoke the factor, not if the time has changed, so I've tried to test that as follows.

I have a spy

```
it('should call the factory only if day changes', function(){
    spyOn(factory, 'getList');
    scope.$broadcast('dateTime', {currentTime:'2017-06-30T00:00:00'});
    scope.$digest();
    expect(factory.getList).toHaveBeenCalledWith('2017-06-30');
    // so far all good, that works, but then I try this.
    scope.$broadcast('dateTime', {currentTime:'2017-06-30T01:00:00'});
    scope.$digest();
    expect(factory.getList).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('2017-06-30');
    // and oh no, we get the error Expected spy unknown not to have been called with [ '2017-06-30' ] but it was.        
});
```

I have checked and debugged the controller, so I know that controller is working correctly and it isn't calling the factory, as the failed test would suggest.

Do I have to reset the spy somehow?  I want to show that with consecutive updates that calling it with just a time change doesn't evoke the factory, so how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you have to reset the spy. It *has* been called, as you’ve just tested. Call its `.calls.reset()` method, per the docs?

Comment: Magic, that fixed it, thank you, I hadn't seen that in the docs, so thanks for pointing that out.